# Rds(on) versus Vgs

Tags: mosfet

I saw this graph in the datasheet of the Supertex (now apparently Microchip) TN0604:

[image]

It shows a lower Rds(on) for a *lower* Vgs. Can that be right? Don't you require a higher Vgs to get a lower Rds(on)?
(My guess is that the 1.0V should be 10V)

Comment: It's a typo probably

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, have a look at other parts of the datasheet:

[image]

\$R_{DS(ON)}\$ always depends on \$V_{GS}\$ and \$I_D\$ ... The higher the voltage, the lower the resistance, but the higher the current, the higher the resistance too, and of course this is not linear.